# How to set build name for queued jobs in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to set build description or set build name for the jobs in Jenkins queue. I know that if we hover over an entry in the queue, we'll see the parameters for particular build. But I want the same information to be displayed along with the build number without hovering.

we can also use the Build Name Setter plugin; but this helps in setting the build description only after the build get triggered. Is there a way to set build name while it is in queue or as soon as the build enters the Jenkins queue?

Comment: It looks like dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69726852/is-there-a-way-to-display-more-information-in-the-jenkins-build-queue-widget no answere there either