# Is there a way to display more information in the Jenkins Build Queue widget?

Tags: jenkins, gerrit

On the jenkins status page, we have the following widget:

[image: jenkins Build Queue widget]

It shows the "master" job pending 5 times (which is reasonable, because each time a code review is pushed to Gerrit, it triggers the job for those changes on that branch.)

If I hover over these "master" links, I can see lots of useful information from the environment, such as GERRIT_CHANGE_NUMBER or GERRIT_EVENT_ACCOUNT_NAME.

Is there some way to get this Build Queue widget to add one of these environment variables to the display item, so I can easily see which change or whose change is pending/building? Or is there some other way to achieve this?

Comment: My idea, yet to try, is to create a folder master, and clone there the original job under array of names that roughly narrow down what it is the job is doing. And have script to pick the right one.
It might be a valid work around for me as I have scripts to create jobs and to spawn the jobs.
It will not cover CHANGE_NUMBER though.

Comment: Did you find any way to do this? if so, please update.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the [Build Name and Description Setter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-name-setter/) Jenkins plugin:

> This plugin sets the display name of a build to something other than
> #1, #2, #3, ... so that you can use an identifier that makes more sense in your context.

Note: don't forget to check the "Set build name before build starts" option.

Comment: Doesn't this require the build to run first?

Comment: Probably, but I hope the "Set build name before build starts" do the trick, but I'm not so confident.

Comment: This is not working on this purpose, It only shows build name well after running, not before.